# Anbox internet connection doesn't work

Tags: networking, 20.04, kubuntu, anbox

Since Whatsapp announced they would stop letting Whatsapp run on my phone (Thanks Facebook), I have been searching for a way to run it on Linux (Kubuntu 20.04). My closest attempt is using Anbox, but that does not connect to the Whatsapp servers to log in. Google chrome Beta also doesn't load websites, but that is just used for testing (I prefer to run Chrome native).

Thanks in advance

Comment: You *always* need a phone, *always*.

Comment: @ChanganAuto what do you mean by that? I've run whatsapp on an Android emulator before.

Comment: @Esther You ALWAYS need at least one device where Whatsapp app is running with an authenticated SIM card / phone number, that's how the service works (it hasn't to be this way but it is, period). Anything else running it works pretty much as Whatsapp web or the desktop clients, i.e., as long as you're *authenticated* with the device that has your phone number then you can open many other instances.

Comment: I do still have a Nokia, so I have a phone. And I have heard people running Whatsapp on a tablet without smartphone

Comment: @Irsu85 Again: You can run it anywhere you want as long as the device that has your phone number is up and running. Please read and understand the comment above. And, BTW, this has nothing to do with Ubuntu, your question is off-topic.

Comment: Why doesn't this have to do with Ubuntu? Or has Kubuntu become off-topic here? (last time I checked it wasn't)

Comment: Yes, you need a *a phone*, but it doesn't even need to be a smartphone. You need a phone number, and you need a device that can run WhatsApp for mobile and pretend well enough to be a phone from WhatsApp's perspective. It has no way of knowing if the device WhatsApp is installed on is the same as the device with the phone number, just that both phone number and app exist.

Comment: Sounds like your issue is that Anbox isn't accessing the internet altogether, is that right? can you test with some other app and see if it gets any internet connection at all?

Comment: Chrome doesn't get connection, Whatsapp doesnt, cant ping from Ubuntu to anbox...

Answer (score 1):

When I started using Anbox, the connection was good. However, the next day the connection was failing. I found a solution that worked for me and it is running this command:

```
sudo systemctl restart snap.anbox.container-manager.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the Anbox github page, which had a script that enabled bridged networking. That seemed to fix my issue, although I still need to fix the lag... The script is availible on https://github.com/anbox/anbox/blob/master/scripts/anbox-bridge.sh